# Getting a JWT with custom claim

Tags: jwt, wso2, token, claims

I need to authenticate users who are not on the wso2 user store so I created a `CustomLocalAuthenticator` that extends `AbstractApplicationAuthenticator` where I implement logic to make calls to external services via the REST API to actually authenticate the users and from these services I retrieve four fields that I will later need as claims to include in the access token. So far, no problem.

In order to insert the claims into the JWT I created `CustomClaimHandler` which extends `DefaultClaimHandler` where I mapped the claims into the `handleLocalClaims` and `handleExternalClaims` methods.
On the identity server (version 5.10.0) I configured the four claims as local claims and external claims and additionally added them as scope openid claims.

Going into debug, the claims in the `CustomClaimHandler` component are correctly set but something causes me to lose the claims just before the access token is generated because the access token that is generated following
to this claim:

```
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?scope=openid&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://localhost/callback&client_id=9_rLhEkjM66KfJNc5xWaJjECvuEa
```

does not contain them.
What could be the problem?
Do you have any useful examples for this use case to share?